# How to read data from USB Port?

Tags: c, usb

I never done the Universal Serial Bus port data read using C. I wanted to know how can data be read of Universal Serial Bus port using C language.

Answer (score 5):

You can look at something like [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/), but you also should read up on USB basics. It's a bus, not a "port", so there is a lot more complexity than you might be expecting.